# Does Rinkeby Faucet Test Net send real ether?

Tags: coinbase, rinkeby

I just got the MetaMask Chrome Extension. I received 3 Ethers from the [Rinkeby Faucet](https://faucet.rinkeby.io/) and sent it to my Ethereum address on Coinbase. Will I receive real money? I'm new to this.

Comment: friends, send me please some ETH in Rinkeby, faucets did not work, thanks! 0x33aba30f38f606a8539E42DE239d5c6E05eB6058

Comment: So what then can one fo with it? What is it for ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The test-nets (such as Rinkeby) can be thought of as an alternate dimension for all intents and purposes.  They are a place to run experiments without modifying the real Ethereum network.  The ether there isn't worth anything, but your mistakes there also don't have consequences.  If you die on Rinkeby, you don't die in real-life ;)

Answer (score 4):

You will **not** receive ether sent from a testnet to your Coinbase account, which is connected to the mainnet. They are separate Ethereum instances and have separate ledgers.

Answer (score 0):

No, the utility of testnet Ether is that you can use it on testnet versions of applications and have a preview of what you would get on the real Ether versions.